# Cannot execute shell /bin/zsh when execute a shell command in vi

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, vi

I use bash. But it cannot find zsh. How to change this?

ps:I don't want to install zsh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set default shell in vim

```
:set shell=/bin/bash
```

Thanks to [Ubuntu Forum](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=379312)

Comment: It works once! How can I make it permanent?

Comment: Add this line to ~/.vimrc     set shell=/bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

have you installed zsh? Install it from here [zsh](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/zsh) [image: Install zsh]

Answer (score 2):

To install zsh type the following in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you propose using Zsh if you don't have it installed?!

You still do have to install it with:

`sudo apt-get install zsh`

even if you don't make it your default shell, which is what I suspect you meant.